# How can I speed up this query?

Tags: index, performance, mariadb, mariadb-10.1, query-performance

Here is the definition of the relevant table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pricehistory (
        id INTEGER(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        price INTEGER NOT NULL,
        region VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
        is_from_api INTEGER DEFAULT 0)
```

Here is the query at issue:

```
SELECT MAX(price) AS price 
FROM pricehistory 
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(timestamp, '+00:00', 'SYSTEM')) 
      > 
      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1000 DAY), '+00:00', 'SYSTEM')) 
  AND region='us';
```

Here is the Explain

```
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: pricehistory
type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
key: NULL
key_len: NULL
ref: NULL
rows: 368040
Extra: Using where
```

Ok so this query runs really slow. I think it takes about 500ms to run for only **300k-400k rows**.

**Roughly 1/5 of all the rows have a region='us'**. If I remove the UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function it drops the run time by about 100ms so I'll probably do that.

I've tried indexing, but I'm new to indexing and have never done it before. All the indexing I've done has either had no effect or slowed the query down even more.

I need the max price in the last `x` days, of only 1/5 of the rows (region='us') in the whole table. I can't think of a way to build an index out of that.

**Note**: I also have a query that gets the minimum price.

Server version: 10.1.35-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution.

Comment: 1) `timestamp` in WHERE section is a filed name in a table? 2) How many records does the table stores, and what part of them matches the WHERE condition? 3) Show table's DDL and EXPLAIN. 4) Specify server version.

Comment: Regarding your comment about how indexing has slowed a query down even more: Be aware that the first time you run a query that uses a new index, that index will have to be populated into the buffer cache. That can slow down the query. When testing any query, either for the first time, or after adding an index, always discard the first result and re-run it. The second query will be a more accurate measure.

Comment: Thanks @WillemRenzema good to know. I ran each one about 5 times each. And yes `timestamp` is a field.

Answer (score 4):

Because your `WHERE` clasue referencing `timestamp` has the column wrapped in a function, it is not going to be able to use an index efficiently to may currently be scanning the whole table.

An index on `region` may help, but not a lot unless that column is quite selective (or at all if the majority of the rows are from the region you are looking at).

As you are applying the same functions to the column and the value you are searching through it with, you can just drop that: the inequality

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(timestamp, '+00:00', 'SYSTEM')) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1000 DAY), '+00:00', 'SYSTEM'))
```

is exactly equivelant to just

```
timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1000 DAY)
```

and that will allow in index on `timestamp` to be useful.

With that change in place, a combined index on both `timestamp` and `region` is likely to be most helpful here. Perhaps also adding `price` to the end then the query running will not need separate lookups to find that column after filtering by the others (though this will increase the size of the index so you are trading space for perhaps only a small amount of speed).

Comment: Is there a difference between an index of `(timestamp, region)` vs `(region, timestamp)`? And what do you mean by "adding `price` to the end"?

Comment: @david2278 Indexes are copies of the data from the main table, sorted first by the leftmost column, then by the next column, etc. So `(timestamp,region)` is only somewhat helpful as while it is easy to find the point for when the records start being greater than your cutoff, it still has to check each row to see if the region matches your value. But, `(region,timestamp)` allows it to immediately find all records for the given region, and then find the records that are greater than your cutoff for the timestamp.  "Adding `price` to the end" means have `(region,timestamp,price)` as your index.

Comment: @david2278 - to be most effective for a given query a compound index should have the most selective column first. Which this is depends on the data balance and what you are searching for, and for similarly selective properties is matters less than other considerations. Adding price to the index even though you aren't searching/sorting with it saves extra lookups into the main table's data pages to get that data. As you *are* effectively sorting by it to look for the highest value adding it in reverse order (`region, timestamp, price DESC` or `timestamp, region, price DESC`) will help here.

Comment: @DavidSpillett - "Selectivity" only applies when comparing two different indexes.  It does not matter when ordering a composite index.

Comment: The `DESC` attribute in an `INDEX` is ignored (until MySQL 8.0).

Comment: @RickJames - the reason to be concerned with selectivity is in choosing which indexes to provide. If you have both `col1, col2` and `col2, col1` it will matter little but if you only have `col`, col2` and column one is not very selective (for a given query) then a full index scan or worse a table scan may be used instead. You may not want to provide both indexes for space/memory reasons.

Comment: @RickJames - regarding the use of `DESC`, how does MySQL8+ relate to the MariaDB 10.x that they are using? I'm a bit out of touch on where the two have diverged/not.

Comment: @DavidSpillett - AFAIK, MariaDB had not yet picked up any of the features new to MySQL 8.0.  The two products are diverging more and more, so I expect fewer things to get 'cross ported'.  Facebook, for example, considered retrofitting 8.0's data dictionary into 5.7, but decided it was too big a task.  Instead they are skipping 5.7.  This may imply that the DD may not make it into MariaDB.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX(price) AS price 
  FROM pricehistory 
  WHERE timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1000 DAY)
    AND region='us';
```

Should reduce the cpu needed to fetch this result.  An combined index on region and timestamp (or timestamp and region) may speed things up even more.

Comment: What's the difference between indices of `region and timestamp` vs `timestamp and region`?

Comment: The order of the columns in the index. You really need to study RDBMS a little more.

Comment: The part that is tested with `=` must come first.  Once you hit 'range', the rest of the index is not useful for filtering.

Comment: @RickJames wrong on both counts.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I know it's been a while, but could you elaborate on why he's wrong?

Comment: @david2278 if the engine can use the index for filtering, it will be much faster than when it has to check the table. That's only possible when the timestamp is part of the index.

Answer (score 1):

- Try to avoid converting timezones.  The `TIMESTAMP` datatype stores UTC and converts according to your tz as you insert/select.
- Don't hide a column in a function if you want to use an index:  Instead of `f(ts) > ...`, do `ts > g(...)`
- After the above, add `INDEX(region, ts)` (in *this* order) as a better index for the better query.
- Even better is to make this "covering" index: `INDEX(region, ts, price)`.

Since such a high percentage of rows has `region='us'`, the Optimizer decides that simply scanning the table, tossing out irrelevant rows, is probably faster than bouncing between the index's BTree and the data.  With my suggestions, the index will be useful and will be used.

You can probably get both the min and max in the same query without doubling the time.

More on index creation:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql